# The EntitySet 'sproc_Forums_GetForumGroupByID' is not defined in the EntityContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I get this error after I've imported a stored procedure then create a complex type and name the function import "sproc_Forums_GetForumGroupByID" this procedure gets a single forum from a ObjectDataSource once the GridView is selected. I get the error on the line of the ExecuteReader. I already have one stored procedure working with the entity framework and it works perfectly I don't understand whats going wrong when I started my second procedure

The EntitySet 'sproc_Forums_GetForumGroupByID' is not defined in the EntityContainer 'CMSEntities'. Near simple identifier, line 1, column 13.

```
public class Forums
{
    public Forum GetForumGroup(int ForumGroupID)
    {
        using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection("name=CMSEntities"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            EntityCommand cmd = new EntityCommand("CMSEntities.sproc_Forums_GetForumGroupByID", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ForumGroupID", ForumGroupID);


                using (EntityDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                {
                    /*
                    Forum forum = null;
                    int forumID = (int)reader[0];
                    string addedBy = reader[1].ToString();
                    DateTime addedDate = (DateTime)reader[2];
                    string title = reader[3].ToString();
                    string updatedBy = reader[4].ToString();
                    DateTime updatedDate = (DateTime)reader[5];
                    bool active = (bool)reader[6];

                    forum = new Forum(forumID, addedBy, addedDate, title, "", 0, 0, false, "",
                        updatedBy, updatedDate, active, "", 0, "", DateTime.Now, "");
                    return forum;*/
                }               

                return null;

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: check your entity model(.edmx file) to verify the existence of your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that the sp exists in the database.
2. Update the entity model.
3. use 'Import Function' in your model browser to import stored procedure.

As a sidenote, I usually use my stored procedures as following.
IMO it's simpler than using EntityDataReader.

```
public Forum GetForumGroup(int forumGroupID)     
{
    using(CMSEntities cmsContext = new CMSEntities())
    {
       var forum = cmsContext.sproc_Forums_GetForumGroupByID(forumGroupID);
       //...
    }
}
```